# Join object values into a string with dynamic key names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

In an Angular app, I have an HTTP response from the server as a JSON object with some errors. I want to join them all into a string and show them as a message to the user.

At the moment, I have done this:

```
if ( "errors" in emsg.error ) {
   let msg = emsg.error.map(o => o.name).join(', ');
}
```

However, I need to write it for every different case of return with different key names. An example of my response is this one:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "message":"422 Unprocessable Entity",
      "errors":{  
         "id":[  
            "The id has already been taken."
         ],
         "name":[  
            "The name has already been taken."
         ]
      },
      "status_code":422
   }
}
```

So, my response can have dynamic object names and each of them may have more than one error. Is there any way to transform the above to a generic code that will handle all the responses of the same format?

Comment: Are you saying the object name `error` might change dynamically? or `errors`?

Comment: any reason why iteration using for-in or forEach won't work?  Or have you not tried that?

Comment: @RaR the keys "id" and "name" may change based on the form submission.

Comment: @ryanlutgen I have tried it, but I was looking for a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the object keys and iterate the keys array. If the keys exist then join the values

```js
var emsg = {  
   "error":{  
      "message":"422 Unprocessable Entity",
      "errors":{  
         "id":[  
            "The id has already been taken."
         ],
         "name":[  
            "The name has already been taken."
         ]
      },
      "status_code":422
   }
}
 var keys = Object.keys(emsg.error.errors);
 let msg = keys.map(o =>emsg.error.errors[o] ).join(', ');
 console.log(msg)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var emsg = {
   "error":{
      "message":"422 Unprocessable Entity",
      "errors":{
         "id":[
            "The id has already been taken."
         ],
         "name":[
            "The name has already been taken."
         ]
      },
      "status_code":422
   }
}, array = [];

// push all error values into array
for (var key in emsg.error.errors) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(array, emsg.error.errors[key]);
}

console.log(array.join(', '));
```

If you can use `lodash`, you can use `flatMap` to do it more elegantly,

```
_.flatMap(emsg.error.errors).join(', ');
```